# For dictionaries in the non-programming sense, what's the right tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What tag should be used for questions about dictionaries in the colloquial sense, like [Any publicly available word dictionary in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45930699/4518341) I.e. a list of words, probably with definitions.

(I don't know how many questions like this we get, so maybe it's not a big concern, but I'm curious if nothing else.)

I don't think the [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) tag is correct since it's about the data structure. The excerpt says: "A dictionary maps keys to values allowing efficient retrieval of values by keys."

I considered:

- [word-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-list), but that wouldn't include definitions, I don't think
- [corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corpus), but that's more general
- [vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), but it's about *dictionary-like* data structures
- [definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definition), but it's vague: it's used for questions about defining an identifier **or** seemingly in place of the [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag
- [natural-language-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-dictionary) doesn't exist

Comment: Non-off-topic question likely will be fine with "dictionary" tag... Maybe finding better (not a request for external resources) example would be useful to come up with suggestions.

Comment: @Alexei Fair enough! From a quick search, I can't find any on-topic question with a positive score where this tag would help and other tags wouldn't be more applicable.

Comment: I can see no good reason to tag this concept in a non-programming sense, exactly because it is in a non-programming sense. If I had my way we'd be getting rid of tons of other tags like [tag:tic-tac-toe], too. Even where there is code, the fact that the code is solving a specific, "classic" problem is usually just not relevant to either questions or answers. It's only relevant to people looking for homework help, and even then only barely.

Comment: Colloquial? *[dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dictionary#Noun)*: *"1. A reference work with a list of words from one or more languages, normally ordered alphabetically, explaining each word's meanings (senses), and sometimes also containing information on its etymology, pronunciation, usage, semantic relations, and translations, as well as other data."*  (self-reference not intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consensus in the comments is that there doesn't need to be a tag for this, as a non-programming concept. Plus there are few questions about it anyway, and I wasn't able to find a single high-quality question at that.